# How can I add another EditorActionHandler to a single IdeAction without losing functionality?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I have a plugin where I would like to add additional functionality when the user triggers the <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd> and <kbd>DELETE</kbd> key, without losing the initial functionality (in this case, character deletion).

I am trying to override the `EditorActionHandler` for the specified `ideActions.<ACTION_EDITOR_VALUE>`:

```
public class MyPlugin implements BaseComponent {

@Override
public void initializeComponent() {

    final EditorActionManager editorActionManager = EditorActionManager.getInstance();
    EditorActionHandler originalBackspaceHandler = editorActionManager.getActionHandler(IdeActions.ACTION_EDITOR_BACKSPACE);

    EditorActionHandler eaHandler = new EditorActionHandler() {
        @Override
        protected void doExecute(@NotNull Editor editor, @Nullable Caret caret, DataContext dataContext) {
            super.doExecute(editor, caret, dataContext);

            originalBackspaceHandler.execute(editor,caret,dataContext);

            PsiElement e = dataContext.getData(CommonDataKeys.PSI_ELEMENT);
            if(e != null) {
                System.out.println("psi Element" + e.toString());
            }
        }

    };        
  editorActionManager.setActionHandler(IdeActions.ACTION_EDITOR_DELETE,  eaHandler);   

} //initalizeComponent()   
} //MyPlugin
```

Is this the preferred way of overriding `editorAction` handlers while maintaining current functionality? I would like to target other `IdeActions.<VALUES>` and reuse the same `EditorActionHandler`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no common way to override action handlers. Your approach is one of the possibilities.

E.g. [Here](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/xdebugger-impl/src/com/intellij/xdebugger/impl/actions/handlers/XDebuggerSmartStepIntoHandler.java#L400) is a code of `smart step into` handlers for "right arrow", "left arrow", etc. A similar approach is used.